# In Angular how do I access a global variable that is initialized in an iife?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am pretty new to Angular, so please have patience. I am upgrading an app from Asp.net MVC5 to Angular, one of the things this application does is connect to a 3rd party system via downloading a javascript file from that 3rd party to establish credentials and communication through an object. It looks like the object is an iife, so as soon as the js file loads, the object is initialized. I have figured out a way to load the script dynamically in my component by adding it to the head of the document, the problem I am having is how to get a hold of that object in my component once the iife has executed. I know the external file is being loaded and the object initialized because I can see it in the dev tools on the browser. This JavaScript file is not something I can get from npm, or add in my assets folder and unfortunately that is all I am finding so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable inside your component and modify the iife to set that variable with the data you want stored to it like this.

```
export class MyComponent{

    MyNewVariable: string; //or make it whatever type you need

    constructor(){}

    (function(){
        //do stuff
        this.MyNewVariable = data; //data being whatever you want to store in the var
    })();
}
```

Once that's done you can run another function that uses the data somehow.

Comment: The iife is in the 3rd party javascript file that I reference, so I can't do anything to change it. I am trying to figure out how to get a hold of the variable that is declared in the iife and get a reference to it in my component.